# JavaScript only including every even number in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to ask the user a series of questions (this is only for college hence the prompt's and not a proper UI), and to cut down on the LOC I added all the questions to an array called !questions"

For some reason the loop is only including every even number in the array.

The code I am using is below

```
    var questions = ['How old is Mark Zuckerberg?',
                     'How much is he worth?',
                     'How old is Bill Gates?',
                     'How much is he worth?',
                     'How old is Dennis Ritchie?'];

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        prompt(questions[i++]);
    }
```

If anyone could help me to get it prompting every question from the array I would very much appreciate this.

Comment: You are incrementing `i` twice in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 5):

You're incrementing `i` twice each time the loop iterates.

Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    prompt(questions[i]);
}
```

Or:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; )
{
    prompt(questions[i++]);
}
```

Either will increment `i` once per loop iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
prompt(questions[i]);
```

Instead of

```
prompt(questions[i++]);
```

Answer (score 1):

your error is that u put i++, u should only put i, increases so does the loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        prompt(questions[i]);
    }
```